# PDF Text is Being Treated as Objects. Cannot Copy-Paste or Edit as "Normal" Text

Tags: windows-10, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I used to be able to print or save various sources (Word, Gmail, web pages) to PDFs with "normal" text. This is no longer possible. Instead, all text is being treated as objects.

It may or may not be related to the problem, but around the same time that "normal" text was disabled, the cursor changed from a vertical bar to a hand.

New and old PDFs are affected.

*Environment*

- Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5019275)
- Acrobat Pro 10 / Installed Version 3.2.1.650 / Update Version 3.5.0

*Note*: Yes, I am aware that Adobe ceased support for Acrobat Pro 10 in late 2022. However, the problem I am posting about is recent.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: Use either Windows' built-in *Print to PDF*, or an application's *Save as PDF*, such as in Thunderbird and Firefox. In repeated tests, that produces PDF files containing selectable text, rather than as files with the "text" as an image. All of those files can be opened in a variety of readers as *text*, such as [Sumatra PDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader), shown below, [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/), and [PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor), all available in free versions.

[image: Print to PDF has text]

Admittedly, this does not give the features of Adobe *Acrobat* to *compose* the final page layout, but for printing Word documents, email (whether viewed in a dedicated email reader such as *Thunderbird* or in a web browser such as *Firefox*), and web pages, this will produce output with *text*, as well as any inline images, and is far simpler and faster than pasting into *Acrobat*.

Comment: My goal is to paste *from*  a PDF to other types of files, most often Word. I tried all available PDF options within Windows, Firefox, Chrome, and also tried Print Friendly. Nothing works. I tried repairing the Acrobat Pro X install. I wonder if there is a setting in Acrobat Pro X that might be the problem. How/why such a setting was toggled would be a mystery. As is what setting(s) would it be? I have no idea where to look.

Comment: See the answer above: try a free PDF viewer tool, such as Sumatra PDF, for that purpose. They also have the advantage of being *far* quicker to start than Adobe Acrobat, and use fewer resources. These applications do not provide the ability to compose a PDF from scratch, but make far better *readers*.

Comment: Update: I tested files in Acrobat Reader and in Acrobat Pro X on another system. Copy-paste worked as expected. The probIem seems to be just on my system. ~ I stepped through all of the Acrobat Pro 10 preferences & security settings. I did this from the file menu, the Tools pane, and the closed app via Properties. There are no restrictions, no settings to print to images, etc. It's all clean. ~ I appreciate that you offered info about other apps for copy-paste, but it falls short of what I need. I rely heavily on copy-paste within and between PDFs, as well as from-to/to-from other file types.